# change date format into "DD-MM-YYYY"

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I used input type "date" as below,

```
<input type="date" class="form-control input-sm pull-right" name="order_date" placeholder="Created At"
          id="l1" [(ngModel)]="order_date">
```

It gives the result with "YYYY-MM-DD" format.

I need the result as "DD-MM-YYYY" with the input type of "date'.Any idea to overcome this!

Comment: change `value="{{date | date:'dd MM yyyy'}}"` to `value="{{date | date:'dd-MM-y'}}"` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Use `{{date | date:'ddMMyyyy'}}` instead of `{{date | date:'dd MM yyyy'}}`

Comment: It still giving the same result!

Comment: try `{{date | date:'dMy'}}`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
(ngModelChange)=setDate(order_date)
```

And in component:

```
setDate(date:Date){
  payload.date = date; // to save payload 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
{{order_date| formatDate: order_date:'d/M/yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var newDatepickerDate = new Date(23/03/1999);
var startup = newDatepickerDate.toLocaleDateString();
var datePickerdate =startup.replace(/\b(\d\/)/g,'0$1');
var i = datePickerdate;
var dayMonthYear= i.replace(/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(\d{4})/, "$3-$1-$2");
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. For future readers it's far more interesting to see explained *why* this answers the question. Apart from that, you can't count on any predictable output from `toLocaleDateString()` so I wonder if this approach holds any water at all.